# Syntax of the "for" command: whats wrong with line 10 in following batch file?

Tags: date, batch-file

```
   1 echo off
   2 
   3 echo Please enter a date
   4 set /p a=
   5 echo %a%
   6 for /D %%d in (M:\Serienbriefauftrag\*) do (
   7 if not exist %%d\Erledigt\*.bat echo %%d
   8 )
   9 pause
  10 for /d %%b in (dir M:\Serienbriefauftrag\%%d /T:C) 
  11 echo %%b
  12 pause
```

The Code works fine until line 10 (syntax error) the aim is, to get the creation date of the folder compare it with "%a%" and and if it's under the entered date "%a%", the folder should be moved. but somehow...

found a way to get the creation date

```
if not exist %%d\Erledigt\*.bat echo %%~td|findstr /i /l
```

the new task is to make the output "calculateable"

Comment: Please improve the subject line to be more useful to future visitors of the site. As-is, the article risks being closed for being too localized. (Nobody else is going to have a problem on line 10, or if they do, it won't be the same problem you're having.)

Comment: There is missing a 'do' and the 'echo %%b' must be on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1) In line 10 `%%d` is undefined (empty), since the scope of the first loop (where it is defined) is left in line 8.
You can set another variable to `%%d` to be able to use it after the loop ends, but be careful. In batch using `set` in `for` loops is a bit [tricky](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php). To get around the aweful use of delayed variable expansion, I would suggest to you staying inside of the loop while doing your work.

```
@echo off
set /p a=Please enter a date: 
for /d %%d in (M:\Serienbriefauftrag\*) do (
    if not exist %%d\Erledigt\*.bat (
        :: Do whatever you want with %%d in here
        echo "%%d"
    )
)
pause
```

2) The syntax of your second loop is wrong. You are missing the `do` before the loop body and `/d` lets the loop iterate over all folders in a specified directory. `dir M:\Serienbriefauftrag\%%d /T:C` is not a directory but a command.
If you want to iterate over the output of that command, you have to use `/f` and put the contents of the paranthesis in single quotes, like that `('dir M:\Serienbriefauftrag\%%d /T:C')`.